# jQuery mobile pushStateEnabled not working on chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, browser-history

I have a jquery mobile website with links like this

```
<a href="/mypage">click</a>
```

On desktop it works with no problems.

Let's say i'm on "site.com/profile"
If i click that link on safari mobile, it takes me to "site.com/mypage"

On chrome mobile, it takes me to "site.com/profile#/mypage" which crashes the website if i hit refresh

Edit:

I checked all my links and are not with #, i event tried full url (schema://site.com/mypage) and it still goes to #/mypage

Comment: Maybe your code include href = "#", I think you have to make question more clear with code.

Comment: I believe just setting `pushStateEnabled`it is not enough. The full listing of configuration entries is [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/) .Did you see the demos for `rel="external"` and [Linking without Ajax](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/) ?  Hope this helps!